# How to statistically compare pairwise distributions?

Tags: normal-distribution, paired-data

I do 5 different measurements for each of my samples, measurements A to E.
The measurements are gene expression values for different genes, I want to see whether the value of A is correlated to any of the others.
Things I have done:
Plot A against B (C, D, E), see R squared value
Plot the difference between A and B (C, D, E)
Look at the distribution of the differences between A and B (C, D, E), see if it is a normal distribution - but unsure about the conclusions to draw from this

Any suggestions at what I should look out for? At the moment I've not been able to draw any meaningful conclusions.

Comment: Which language are you programming in? You can compute a correlation matrix with a single function call in all of the common languages.